# sitecore template standard values layout not updating all items, layout not loading

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, sitecore, integrated-pipeline-mode

i'm currently having a nightmarish moment with Sitecore. Basically my issues are two-fold:

1) the first time i added a standard value item to a template, and added a layout setup to it, i was thrilled, since all my items from that template were showing the layout, however now, certain items are now showing no layout at all. I tried doing presentation->layout, reset several times, but to no avail.

2) i added a new sublayout to the standard value layout to another placeholder, did publish on the template (republish everything, publish subitems), then publish on the standard values item again, just in case (should not be needed), i click on all items from the template, and they show the updated layout with the new sublayout (should be good, right?) however, i browse, both live and with preview to the pages and i am still seeing the old layout without my new sublayout. 
 - I added a breakpoint in the page_load of the new sublayout but it never hits, the others do
 - I tried cleaning the cache on sitecore/admin/cache.aspx, but did not help
 - tried recycling the app pool, restarting the web site, spreading black rooster' blood over the machine, nothing seems to helps

i am using sitecore 6.2.0 (rev. 100701), visual studio 2008 SP1, IIS7 in integrated mode

Answer (score 1):

> Basically the way to do it is set layout on the Standard Values, which should update all items, that haven't had their layout overwritten on the item or by a branch.

This is the key to the issue.  If your items that aren't getting updated with the template standard value layout were created using a branch, check to make sure that branch does not also have layout details associated with it.  If the branch has layout details in addition to the template, the two will conflict and cause really odd, frustrating behavior.

I encountered the exact same scenario, but after removing the layout details from my branch the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange... usually this only happens, when you have a "conflict" between layout set on Standard Values, template/branch.

Basically the way to do it is set layout on the Standard Values, which should update all items, that haven't had their layout overwritten on the item or by a branch.

I really dislike branches, so always try to avoid them (the only real use when they were Masters were for building hierarchies of items).

Could you try to look in the __layouts field (View > Raw values) of the items and see if anything is entered there?

And is it only some items or all items based on that template?