# How do I use a Branch Template in Sitecore?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore-branch-templates

I have a "Default Template" consisting of a bunch of sublayouts, most importantly the "ContactForm" sublayout. I want to create a Branch Template of the Default Template so that I can change the ContactForm sublayout to a "PressForm" sublayout. What I'm struggling with is exactly how I should do this.

At the moment I have gone into my Branches folder and created a new Branch Template and use my Default Template; I've named it Default Template Branch. I now have an item underneath it called $name which states that it is a Default Template. I can edit this to change the ContactForm sublayout to "PressForm".

Where do I go from here to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$name` is the item instance that you'd want to edit. you should make a Contact branch and a separate Press branch. Then edit each `$name` below according to your changes (e.g. different presentation)

Comment: So, I've created my branch based on the Default Template, renamed it Press Branch and now I've edited the $name to reflect the changes needed. How do I now add this to my content item?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what a branch is, it's a "creator". A content item is an instance of a template. A branch is a creator of an item of a specific template. Your content item should already be on the correct template. Branches are nice as you can predefine subitems below the instances, so when you create a folder it will automatically create subitems as well. It can also be used as in your case to act like a template but apply different values. Once you create the branch you need to update your assign options to no longer point to the template, but instead point to the branch.

Comment: I think I finally get it! If I understand you correctly is that you set the Assign Options on the template above, so that if I have a content item with my branch assigned within that template I can then right-click, click insert and then use the branch? As this seems to work, how would I now do this for existing content items, so that I can get them to be "created from" my Press branch?

Comment: Correct. The branch creates, so you can't make it affect existing items. The branch is just a convenient creator, almost like standard values, with different values. So if you have "Template A" but two separate scenarios to use it with different values, you can create two separates branches for it, each with their different values. Then your assign options can use the two branches instead of "Template A" itself

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for helping me through this!

Comment: Does this solution actually enable the layout goal described in the question, where the branch template is used to swap a certain sublayout?  Documentation, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8329532/665376), and a local test seem to indicate otherwise.  That said, there does seem to be [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523013/sitecore-template-standard-values-layout-not-updating-all-items-layout-not-load) [confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12682931/665376) about this.

Comment: Yes, the branch is a creator. There can be a separate branch for each scenario. Each $name below it will deviate from standard values