# Branch template and consistent layout with sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We are using [EviBlog](http://trac.sitecore.net/EviBlog), and I want the layout change to be consistent whenever I change to layout for the layout template.

However that don't work. The layout get copied and won't change in item, even on fresh new item, when I update the template layout.

I can't use a base template, because EviBlog doesn't check for inheritence, it's check only for direct template ID, when listing.

From want I understand, Standard Value would be helpful, I haven't found a way to specify standard value for Branch Template

Any advice?

Comment: Which EviBlog template does this apply to? Are you saying that if you change the layout details on the standard values of that template, that they don't cascade to items? Or are you changing layout details in the branch?

Comment: I can't change the Entry template since it's shared between website, so my only option is to add layout to the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore items can't inherit from values set in a branch template. They will always default to the values in the original template's standard values. This is a limitation of branches.

If you upgrade to the latest version of WeBlog (the new name for EviBlog), you should be able to create a new Entry templates for each blog, with their own standard values and presentation details.

Depending on how complex the differences are, another option would be to use Conditional Rendering within your standard values.

1. Create new personalization rules under /sitecore/system/Marketing Center/Personalization/Rules for each website
2. Use the built-in condition "where website name compares to value" to make the rule apply to the specific website
3. In the rendering references of your standard values, apply the personalization rule to make renderings only appear for specific sites

More info on Conditional Renderings here:

http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Sitecore-Rules-Engine-and-Conditional-Rendering.aspx

Comment: I can't update for now, and conditional is not an option, but that to confirm I can't use branch template.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but just curious why aren't conditional renderings an option?

Comment: It might be an option, but it doesn't belong there. Having conditionnal programming for specific template for a website in a generic template (Entry), would be wierd and violate separation of concerns.

Comment: FYI, since we use a modified version of EviBlog, it would have been tricky to update it. However, I modified our EviBlog to accept an inherited template. So the branch template is now using XYZEntry instead of EviBlog entry, so now I can inherit layout from XYZEntry.

Comment: Dogmatic but true enough. That's why we fixed it in WeBlog 2.0. Good luck.